# awk, compare field with previous line field and conditionally print both

Tags: awk

I could do this more easily with python/perl but I want to get better at awk and I know this can be achieved with it, I'm not an experienced sysadmin, these are my first scripts in production and I'd be grateful for some help and pointers with this.

I have a file with data like this:

first field is a bufferpool name, second field is program size, third field is program name.

datafile:

```
NATBPG 6286 SPAP303
NATBPG 9170 SPAP303N
NATBPG 1754 SPAP303S
NATBPZ 1754 SPAP303S
NATBPZ 9170 SPAP303N
NATBPZ 6286 SPAP303
NATBPB 6700 SPAP303
```

and another file with all the unique occurrences of program name:

programs:

```
SPAP303S
SPAP303N
SPAP303
```

I need to find all occurrences where the size is not the same across the same or different bufferpools, and when that's the case print out all the program occurrences, so in the above case the desidered output would be like so:

```
NATBPZ SPAP303 6286
NATBPB SPAP303 6700
NATBPG SPAP303 6286
```

so far I have the following snippet of bash+awk code:

```
while read programs; do
    awk -v program="$programs" '{
        if($3==program && prev!=$2)
        {
            print $1,$3,prev;
        }
        else
        {
            print "ok";
        }
        if($3==program)
        {prev=$2}
        }' datafile >> outputfile
done < programs
```

which produces the following output

```
NATBPG SPAP303S 
NATBPG SPAP303N 
NATBPG SPAP303 
NATBPB SPAP303 6286
NATBPG SPAP303S 
NATBPG SPAP303N 
NATBPG SPAP303 
NATBPB SPAP303 6286
```

after a bit of very ugly cleanup (making awk print out only the lines with NR>2) I get an acceptable output, like so:

```
NATBPB SPAP303 6286
NATBPB SPAP303 6286
```

but I am still missing the line

```
NATBPB SPAP303 6700
```

so I have three questions:

1. how do I get the line I'm missing? I tried some combinations of saving my current line in $0 at different stages of my awk programs and printing that out when the conditions were met but I couldn't get it to work
2. why do I actually get this output from my awk program? I thought I was printing out this

> print $1,$3,prev;

only when both conditions where met and else I would print out ok, instead I'm printin the following in my outputfile:

```
NATBPG SPAP303S 
NATBPG SPAP303N 
NATBPG SPAP303 
NATBPB SPAP303 6286
```

and I'm at a loss of where the first three lines are coming from

2. I understand this approach is flawed because it would be better to use some sort of array to store the occurrences of a program while looping over the data programs by program and afterward checking if they all have the same size, if they don't print out the array and go to the next program, is this even possible in awk? I think so but I'm a bit at loss about it.

Comment: `while read programs; do ... done < programs` is a bit confusing.  It seems `while read program; do ... done < programs` would be better.   But you really want to avoid this loop altogether and do everything in awk.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk 'NR==FNR{a[$3][$2];next}length(a[$3])>1' file file
```

Output:

```
NATBPG 6286 SPAP303
NATBPZ 6286 SPAP303
NATBPB 6700 SPAP303

$ gawk 'NR==FNR {          # first iteration 
    a[$3][$2]              # hash entries
    next
}                          # second iteration
length(a[$3])>1' file file # see if $3 has more than one 2nd dim. entries
```